# How can I document the cookie using spring-restdoc?

Tags: spring-mvc, cookies, spring-restdocs

I use the current version spring-restdoc: 1.1.2.RELEASE.

I created an API that needs a cookie in the header. Here is my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}/userInfo", produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<UserInfo> getUserInfo(@CookieValue("identity") String cookie,
                                            @PathVariable(value = "username") String username) {

    LOGGER.info("[getUserInfo] user = {}", username);
    ResponseEntity<UserInfo> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(userService.findUserInfos(cookie, username), HttpStatus.OK);
    LOGGER.debug("[getUserInfo] response = {}", responseEntity.toString());
    return responseEntity;
}
```

After I write my test for the documentation of the getUserInfos. Here is my test:

```
    @Test
public void getUserInfoOK() throws Exception {
    when(userService.findUserInfos(cookieCaptor.capture(), userNameCaptor.capture())).thenReturn(
            createUserInfo());
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("identity", "cookieForTest");

    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath("").path("/v1/users/{username}/userInfo");
    URI uri = builder.build("userTest");
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost:8070" + "/api/user" + "/v1/users/{username}/userInfo", "userTest")
            .header("Host", "localhost")
            .cookie(cookie)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .servletPath(uri.toString()).contextPath("/api/user");

    mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andDo(print())
            .andDo(document("{method-name}", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()), preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()),
                    pathParameters(
                            parameterWithName("username").description("The username's user")),
                    requestHeaders(
                            headerWithName("Cookie").description(
                                    "The cookie that identifies the user"))
            ))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.bouquets", hasSize(3)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    //verify userService.findUserInfos is called
    verify(userService).findUserInfos(anyString(), anyString());

    // verify the parameters
    assertEquals("userTest", userNameCaptor.getValue());
    assertEquals("cookieForTest", cookieCaptor.getValue());
}
```

When I run my test that generates the documentation I have the following error:

```
    org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException: Headers with the following names were not found in the request: [Cookie]

at org.springframework.restdocs.headers.AbstractHeadersSnippet.validateHeaderDocumentation(AbstractHeadersSnippet.java:83)
at org.springframework.restdocs.headers.AbstractHeadersSnippet.createModel(AbstractHeadersSnippet.java:65)
at org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet.document(TemplatedSnippet.java:64)
at org.springframework.restdocs.generate.RestDocumentationGenerator.handle(RestDocumentationGenerator.java:196)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler.handle(RestDocumentationResultHandler.java:55)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andDo(MockMvc.java:177)
at com.orange.otml.otmluser.controller.UsersControllerTest.getUserInfoOK(UsersControllerTest.java:183)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.restdocs.JUnitRestDocumentation$1.evaluate(JUnitRestDocumentation.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

How spring-restdoc manages cookies ? How to document identity cookie using spring-restdoc ?

I have not found words reserved for cookie in spring-restdoc.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no support for documenting Cookies in Spring REST Docs at the moment. You're the first person that I'm aware of that's asked for it. It sounds like a reasonable thing to support so I've opened a few enhancement issues. [This one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/306) is probably the most relevant to your question. If you have an opinion about the two different approaches, or would like to propose another approach, please do comment on the issue.

Comment: Thank-you for your prompt response. I post my opinion in the project github.

Comment: I was looking for exactly the same functionality